# How to extract code comments from a C file?

Tags: c, parsing, extract, doxygen

I have a C file which contains lots of code comments, how I can I extract the comments? Just want the comments, not the c code. Is there any tools i can use to do this. e.g Doxygen? or need i to build a parser by myself? if needed, which language is better?

Thanks in advance.

thank you all!!
i start to look into perl now, have never used this kind of language before, it seems so clever~~  and is there any suggestion for extracting xml from a file that contains xml?

Comment: What are you intentions regarding the comments? Do you need to retain their context, e.g. namespace/class/function/line number, etc.? You could write simple regex and bash script to scrap the comments

Comment: hi, ak

i dont need to retain their context, there are some xml included in the comments, i want to extract them. any suggestion?

thanks

Comment: There is also a [python script](https://gist.github.com/mikeshi80/5524036) from [cppblog](http://www.cppblog.com/luyulaile/archive/2012/12/03/195907.html) that allows to extract all comments. Use as ```python extractcomments.py foo.c```. It will give you foo_cmt.txt. It gives (for me at least) the exact same result as the awk script from [mzet answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7471827/1879269) below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suggest you to use an scripting language, such as Perl, and parse the file looking all the possibilities:

```
 - "//" for single-line comments.
 - "/*" and "*/" for multi-line comments.
 - doxygen ones "///", "/**", "/*!"
```

Comment: Actually, it looks like there is already a perl module for this on [cpan](http://search.cpan.org/~rokr/String-Comments-Extract-0.023/lib/String/Comments/Extract.pm).

Comment: Yes!!that´s what i want! i start to look into perl now, have never used  this kind of language before, it seems so clever~~ thank you all. and is there any suggestion for extracting xml from a file that contains xml?

Comment: It is not so simple. `printf("//hi");` is not a comment.

Answer (score 5):

Following one-liner displays all commented lines (or lines that contain comments) in main.c file:

```
cat main.c | awk '/\/\// {print $0}; /\/\*/ {blk=1}; {if(blk) print $0}; /\*\// {blk=0}'
```

Comment: And does so poorly. The line `printf("//hi");` is not a comment.